# Insert rows for records that exists with a distinct id

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'd like to insert a row for each distinct id that exists in my table. What is the best and efficient practice to add these rows for each distinct id?

```
ID      Name        Count
--      ----        ---
A1      ABC          4
A1      BCD          2
B1      KLM          1
C2      STU          3
C2      BCD          1
C2      DEF          5
```

EXPECTED RESULT AFTER INSERT

```
ID      Name        Count
--      ----        ---
A1      ABC          4
A1      BCD          2
A1      EXISTS       1
B1      KLM          7
B1      EXISTS       1
C2      STU          3
C2      BCD          4
C2      DEF          5
C2      EXISTS       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all`:

```
select id, name, count
from t
union all
select distinct id, 'EXISTS', 1
from t;
```

An insert is even simpler:

```
insert into t (id, name, count)
    select distinct id, 'EXISTS', 1
    from t;
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was ambiguous earlier but I was expecting an insert query. And I guess only second part of the union would be needed for that.